# get the IndexPath.row and IndexPath.section Before Creation of the table View

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, reload, uitableview

I want to update a particular `UITableViewCell` into the Swift IOS.

"`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`" is used for updating the particular `UITableViewCell`,

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

My Concern is "How to get the `IndexPath.row` and `IndexPath.section`" `([indexPath]` for this Case ) before creating the `UITableView` , i want to pass both to update the particular `UItableViewCell`.

Comment: Why will you update a cell even before its created ?? Will not make any sense :) cells gets generated when your tableview is loaded and cellforRowAtIndexpath is called :) reloading a cell even before tableview is created it will not have any effect in Objective C might crash in swift :)

Comment: Right agree with @SandeepBhandari. Question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can **re**load something only if has been loaded once ;-)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Then how i will update the table view , need to traverse Entire table view and get the Individual table view cell  index ?? please suggest me the approach , My Only Concern it to update the particular table view cell , without traversing the entire table view

Comment: @Lion   now its clear where i  am wrong , want to know can i update the tableview without traversing the entire tableView

Comment: @IosAlo : You need to undertsand the concept of tableview buddy :)  When you load a tableview, all the cells in visible range will get loaded :) not all the cells in tableview :) When they get loaded they will update their UI properly correct ?? and if the cell you want to "update" is not in the visible rows range, it will get updated when user scrolls down to see that cell :) you dont have to do any thing :)

Comment: @IosAlo : now if you are wondering why apple provided with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths then ?? Simple :) assume you have to show images like profile image of users in each row :) those images needs to downloaded from server :) now you cant download them in main thread correct ?? So you start a background thread to download :) once image is downloaded if you have to show cell needs to be reloaded right you cant expect user to scroll to see the updated image isn't it :) So in such situations in which your tableview is already loaded and yet you have to update a specific cell u'll use this method :)

Comment: @IosAlo : Now if you are thinking why the hell cant I reload the whole table in that case ? You can buddy :) Reloading the tableview will reload all the visible cells :) but why to waste cpu cycle to update 5-10 cells when all I need is to update one cell ??? So use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to improve the performance :) I hope I made a little sense in my very lengthy answer :)

Comment: Got it Brother , need to go through the Concept , thanks for the Help , thanks a Lot :)
sorry for the such a idiotic question , fresher in this field !!

Comment: @IosAlo : never be sorry for asking the question buddy :) we have all gone through the same phase :) read and learn now, you will help somebody some day with the concept :) all the best happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the help !! yes sure i wast to delete the post , but now won't , as it will surely help some other guy lacking with the Concept in his/her early phase of coding , :)

Comment: @iosalo : Deleting question is your call bro :) Emotions might cost few points in stack over flow if you get some down-vote :P hehehehehehehehe

Answer (score 0):

```
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

With this you can init a NSIndexPath variable. [] brackets because reloadRowsAtIndexPath wants an array of those as parameter.

Parameters in NSIndexPath initializer are pretty straight forward i guess (forRow --> which row | inSection --> which section

hf ;)

Comment: Doesn't work or make sense before creation of TableView

Comment: thats not even his concern i guess. How i understand his question, he wants to know how to reload one specific row. and this DOES work buddy, try it (when tableview is created)

Comment: have you read the heading? "get the IndexPath.row and IndexPath.section Before Creation of the table View" and also the comments under his question?...

Comment: Still, in my opinion, he is struggling to get the NSIndexPath variable where he needs it. "get the IndexPath.row and IndexPath.section Before Creation of the table View" doesn't necessarily mean he wants to reload before creation, but  wants to get the NSIndexPath variable beforehand.

Comment: Please, read his comments. he was struggeling with base caoncepts of the UItableView class, not with this index-getting-issue itself.